# Swift - Firebase add multiple value with same key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, addition, onesignal

I am trying to collect the OneSignalIDs of the users.
The following code adds one playerID for each user.
When the same user logs in with a different device, the playerID is updated.

```
    let status : OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
    let oneSignalUser = status.subscriptionStatus.userId

    if oneSignalUser != nil {
        let aUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!

        let post = ["playerID": oneSignalUser!] as [String: Any]
        Database.database().reference().child("usersToOneSignal").child(aUser.uid).setValue(post)
    }
```

[image]

I want every user to be added to every device. 
So I want more than one playerID under the key "kwvZPH......" (this is FireBase UserKey).
How can I do this?

Comment: Use updateChildValues() as shown in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) :=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by saving the OneSignal ID as the key instead of the value. Then the `playerID` won't be overridden on login to a new device. The value doesn't matter, as long as it exists (I will set it to `true`).

```
let status : OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
let oneSignalUserID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId

if oneSignalUser != nil {
    let aUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!

    // get the original path you were using
    let originalPath = Database.database().reference().child("usersToOneSignal").child(aUser.uid)
    // set `true` at the OneSignal key in the database
    originalPath.child(oneSignalUserID!).setValue(true)
}
```

Will give a database:

```
- usersToOneSignal
     |
     | - kwzphiusgdfoiaudbksdhf763truygi
       |
       | - 4e762345-76654afedc-65342287fc-57635472: true
       | - 7645736-efcab873465-7635476823f-ab62354: true
```

Obviously you will need to change how you retrieve the values.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to create a ChildKey from the UIDevice...uuidstring. But your method is much more useful.